# Previous function not working

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, slideshow

I'm working on a javascript slideshow but I'm not sure how to add a caption to each image, the previous button is not working properly (shows no image after two or more clicks) also how would I also be able to go to the first and last image of the slides?

```
var index=4;
var titles=[1,2,3,4,5];


// LIST OF CAPTİONS
caption[0] = "Caption for the first image";
caption[1] = "Caption for the second image";
caption[2] = "Caption for the third image";
caption[3] = "Caption for the first image";
caption[4] = "Caption for the second image";
caption[5] = "Caption for the third image";

function NextSlide()
{
    if (index >= 5){index=0}
    var img = document.getElementById("img1");
    var slideName="images/img" + titles[index++] + ".jpg";
    img.src=slideName;
}

function PrevSlide()
{
    if (index >= 5){index=0}
    var img = document.getElementById("img1");
    var slideName="images/img" + titles[index--] + ".jpg"; img.src=slideName;
}
function last()
{
    index = 1;
}
```

Comment: Where is `caption` defined ?

Comment: When you call `PrevSlide` you never check to see if you go less than zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code gives an example how you might implement the first() and last() methods as well as changing the caption.  You haven't provided any HTML so it may need testing/tweaking to fit with what you've got (e.g. you'll need to add a `span` or `p` tag to contain the caption with ID of `caption1`)

```
var index = 3;   // index for forth image as it's zero based

// List of captions
var captions  = ["Caption for the first image",
                 "Caption for the second image",
                 "Caption for the third image",
                 "Caption for the forth image",
                 "Caption for the fifth image",
                 "Caption for the sixth image"];

var slideShowImg = document.getElementById("img1");
var slideShowCaption = document.getElementById("caption1");

// Show current image
function showCurrentImage(){
    var slideName = "images/img" + (index + 1) + ".jpg";
    slideShowImg.src = slideName;
    slideShowCaption.innerText = captions[index];
}

// Move to next slide
function nextSlide()
{
    index++;
    if (index >= captions.length){ index = 0; }

    showCurrentImage();
}

// Move to previous slide
function prevSlide()
{
    index--;
    if (index < 0){ index = captions.length - 1; }

    showCurrentImage();
}

// Move to last slide
function last()
{
    index = captions.length - 1;

    showCurrentImage();
}

// Move to first slide
function first()
{
    index = 0;

    showCurrentImage();
}
```

HTML could be something like...

```
<div class="slide-show">
  <img src="#" id="img1" alt="" />
  <span id="caption1">Caption</span>
</div>
```

Notes:

- Your variable `titles` was just adding one to index so I removed that and added inline.
- I've moved captions into a single line rather than define one by one.
- Moved getElementById("img1") out of the method as it just repeats itself each time
- Created showCurrentImage() to do the changes to the page, all the other methods simply change the index then call this
- Fixed your test for the first item in prevSlide() (looked like it was copied from nextSlide()

Comment: Thanks fir the advice, my HTML code was this                                                '<p><img id="img1" src="img1.jpg" width="500" height="500"></p>'                  however what would be the best way to display the image?

Comment: Not sure what your question is?  You already have the image displaying ok via the `img` tag don't you?  If you mean visually have a look at how other slide show libraries work, in particular things like pre-loading the next image and fade transitions from one image to the next.

Comment: Well I'm having issues viewing it in in different browsers and when I upload the page. It's the "slideShowImg.src = slideName;" part, I get "Uncaught TypeError: cannot set property 'src' of null"

Comment: It means `slideShowImg` is null which means it can't find the image in the DOM.  Suspect you just have a typo in your code somewhere.  Check the id on the `IMG` tag and the `getElementById()` part to make sure they look correct.  Otherwise you may need to post a link to your code or ask another question.

Comment: I checked it and I can see any issues with it. `var slideShowImg = document.getElementById("img1");
var slideShowCaption = document.getElementById("caption1");

// Show current image
function showCurrentImage(){
    var slideName = "images/img" + (index + 1) + ".jpg";
    slideShowImg.src = slideName;
    slideShowCaption.innerText = captions[index];
}' and heres the HTML `<div><img src="images/img1.jpg" id="img1" width="400" height="400">
            <span id="caption1">captions</span>
            </div>`

Comment: Press F12 in Chrome, go to Console tab and paste `document.getElementById("img1")`.  See if it gives `null` or not.

Comment: No it's not given me null, just the HTML img tag

Comment: Oh, it's probably a timing issue.  Your JS is running before the DOM is loaded (before the image exists in the DOM).  Simple way to solve this is put your SCRIPT tag at the bottom of the HTML page.  Otherwise it needs to be in a document onload event.